# If two parallel lines meet at infinity, then what is their angle?

Tags: calculus, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, recreational-mathematics

Since lines that meet at some point have an angle. And if parallel lines meet at infinity, then that what is the angle of two parallel lines that meet at infinity?

Comment: Under what geometry

Comment: I'm not an expert, but isn't this a contradiction under real analysis? To meet at infinity would mean that infinity must end, which is false.

Comment: The two premises of the question ("lines that meet at some point have an angle" and "parallel lines meet at infinity") are badly formulated. Anyway, under any reasonable reformulation of them, the answer is : the angle is zero.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear the OP is talking about lines in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$.  @leonbloy, why don't you add some explanation to your comment and make it into an answer?

Comment: @rb612 I don't understand your comment at all.  Projective geometry, including the [line at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_at_infinity), is a perfectly sensible thing to talk about.  Your comment about "infinity must end" does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @SpamIAm you're right. I was thinking this was referring to ordinary plane geometry only.

Comment: Lets take the Riemann sphere, where infinity is a north pole. Stereographic projection (that preserves angles) transforms lines into the circles. [Just after Theorem 3.3.4](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=yveG5B1few4C&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=Stereographic+projection+paralle) the angle of intersection for parallel lines is defined to be 0.

Comment: Even more, the angle is zero because [it equals the angle between tangent lines](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=LgeP62-ZxikC&lpg=PA24&ots=jm6rlYb1st&dq=riemann%20sphere%20angle%20between%20tangent%20lines&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=%22angle%20between%20the%20tangent%22&f=false)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is gibberish.

Comment: This question is decidedly not a duplicate of the linked thread.  The word "angle" does not even appear once in the other post